# How can I access .a library files in Perl?

Tags: perl

How can I access .a library files in Perl?

Comment: What do you mean by `access`? Load? Link? List objects/functions?

Comment: Do you suppose: `my $lib = "libname.a"; print "Accessed $lib\n" if -f $lib;` counts?

Answer (score 4):

Convert your static library to a dynamic one, then use the usual ways to load it: [`XSLoader`](http://p3rl.org/XSLoader) / [`DynaLoader`](http://p3rl.org/DynaLoader), [perlxs](http://p3rl.org/xs) / [`C::DynaLib`](http://p3rl.org/C::DynaLib)

Conversion steps (not fully tested): `ar -x lib.a; gcc -shared *.o -o lib.so`

Comment: What you've described gives the raw C functions - but you probably need the XS wrapping too.